# PostConstruct of JSF bean calling more than once

Tags: spring, cdi, jsf-2.2

I have the following managed bean (removed some lines):

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;

@ManagedBean
@FlowScoped(value="create-colaborator")
public class CriarProfessionalController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6578310438927368912L;

    @ManagedProperty("#{professionalService}")
    private IProfessionalService professionalService;

    @ManagedProperty("#{territorioService}")
    private ITerritorioService territorioService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.profissional = new Professional();
        this.setTipoDeDocumentos(tipoDocumentoService.buscaTodos());
        this.setProvincias(territorioService.buscaTodosProvincias());
    }
}
```

I have to added CDI to use FlowScope in JSF, so I have the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.14.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And in my faces-config.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">    
    <application>           <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>    
</faces-config>
```

It seems that it is not using the flowscope!

Comment: JSF managed beans do not know about the CDI flow scoped so they effectively are without a scope (try removing it, the behaviour is the same). Might I suggest to fully switch to CDI and also to update the web.xml version (2.5 has been superseeded by 3.0 and 3.1) and you a more recent one plays more nicely with JSF 2.2

Comment: thanks @Kukeltje I change to CDI. Can I use the flowscope of JSF with CDI? I try but now the postconstruct is only called once. If I try to start the flow the postconstruct method is not called.